# How to save a value to increment in a recursive function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, recursion

```
var count = 0;
var NumbOfNodes = function(root){

   if(root.left != null){
       NumbOfNodes(root.left);
   }

   count++;

   if(root.right != null){
       NumbOfNodes(root.right);
   }

   return count;
}
```

So I have this function that counts the number of nodes in a tree. It is a recursive function. When I make count a global variable, the function works and returns a proper value. The problem is, I want count to be part of the function. But if I declare count inside the function, it keeps on getting reset and I wont get a proper answer fro the function.

So, is there a way to preserve the value of a variable inside a recursive function. This question can help me in many other coding practices.

What I want (Diagram): Tree --> NumbOfNodes() --> gives me the number of nodes. But I don't want to make a global variable just for it.

Thanks!

Comment: You can add an extra int parameter to your function, pass in 0 always to start. Then increment as normally would in function to count the nodes and  return it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just return the count from within the recursion:

```
var NumbOfNodes = function(root) {
    var count = 0;
    if (root.left != null) {
        count += NumbOfNodes(root.left);
    }

    count++;     // count ourself

    if (root.right != null) {
        count += NumbOfNodes(root.right);
    }

    return count;
}
```

The basic idea here is that, at each step of the recursion, we start with a count of zero.  Then we add to that count the number of nodes in the left and right subtrees, *and* we add one, to count ourself.

Comment: Hmm, this is the best solution to this so far, Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

do you really need an extra variable to maintain count?

try this,

```
var NumbOfNodes = function(root){
   if(!root){
    return 0;
   }   
   return NumbOfNodes(root.right) + NumbOfNodes(root.left) + 1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the `count` as an argument to that function like

```
var NumbOfNodes = function(root, count){
   if(!count) count = 0;

   if(root.left != null){
       NumbOfNodes(root.left, count);
   }

   count++;

   if(root.right != null){
       NumbOfNodes(root.right, count);
   }

   return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since NumOfNodes is a variable itself it is an instance and you can use this.count to cache itself as a value

```
var NumbOfNodes = function(root){
  if (this.count === undefined) {
    this.count = 0;
  }

   if(root.left != null){
       NumbOfNodes(root.left);
   }

   this.count++;

   if(root.right != null){
       NumbOfNodes(root.right);
   }

   return this.count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for the variable's value to be preserved, you need to pass it recursively. Something like:

```
var NumbOfNodes = numberOfNodes(roots, 0)

function numberOfNodes(root, count){

    if(root.left != null){
        numberOfNodes(root.left, count);
    }

    count++;

    if(root.right != null){
        numberOfNodes(root.right, count);
    }

    return count;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to save a value to increment in a recursive function (Javascript)

Well you don't need to save a value in order to calculate the number of nodes. When designing a recursive function, just think about the **base** and **inductive** case(s)

- base case - the `node` is empty, return a count of 0
- inductive case - the `node` is *not* empty, return 1 for this node, *plus* the count of this node's `left` and `right` nodes.

Our `countNodes` function almost writes itself

```js
const Empty =
  Symbol ()

const Node = (value = null, left = Empty, right = Empty) =>
  ({ Node, value, left, right })
  
const countNodes = (node = Empty) =>
  node === Empty
    ? 0
    : 1 + countNodes (node.left) + countNodes (node.right)
    
console.log
  ( countNodes ()                                       // 0

  , countNodes (Node (0))                               // 1

  , countNodes (Node (0, Node (1), Node (2)))           // 3

  , countNodes (Node (0, Node (1, Node (2), Node (3))
                       , Node (4, Node (5), Node (6)))) // 7
  )
```